# 'oracledb' Oracle Client Library errors ( Error: NJS-045 and other errors)

Tags: node.js, npm-install, require, node-oracledb, instantclient

I have installed the oracledb library to my project folder by using the command

'npm i oracledb --s'

it has successfully installed, and it is in the folder 'node_modules' inside my project. Inside the project folder, I also have the 'instantclient' folder, after downloading it and opening it.

When I try to run my program, the following errors occur:

*at require (internal/module.js:11:18) 
at Object. (c:\Users\tlobel\Documents\Install_1\node_modules\oracledb\index.js:1:80) 
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30) 
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect... 
**Error: NJS-045: cannot load the oracledb add-on binary for Node.js 8.11.1** (win32, x64)
oracledb.js:68
Cannot load c:\Users\tlobel\Documents\Install_1\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node
**DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher**
Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
**You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in your PATH environment variable**.
If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html
**A Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable suitable for your Oracle client library version must be available**.*

My **PATH** looks like this:

*PATH=C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts; C:\Users\usr1\My Documents\Install_1\instantclient;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\usr1\Downloads\Git-2.16.2-64-bit;C:\Users\usr1\Downloads\VC_redist.x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\usr1\AppData\Roaming\npm*

and my project is located in the folder:  *C:\Users\usr1\My Documents\Install_1*

I have also downloaded the VS redistributable, but I don't know where to put it...
Anyone know which problems must be solved for this to work?

Answers very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I recently came unstuck with a similar error.  Initially, I had no issues using this package and it didn't require further dependencies to be installed.  However, I upgraded Node the other week and had to then upgrade oracledb and then got similar error to what you have.

The git hub page for the package is really helpful and describes what you need to additionally install on your host server.

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb

Comment: The node-oracledb installation instructions for Windows are at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html#instwin

Answer (score 0):

Install Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher.
And set the bin path in Environments variable.

Answer (score -1):

The last thing written here:

https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/898

Helped sort things out - recommend a try!

Comment: This answer is not at all helpful. Please elaborate more on this. Instead of going to the last of the above-mentioned thread simply state the point here as well.